# Indefinite matrix warning in panel regression

Tags: r, linear-regression, logistic-regression, longitudinal

I am using the `lfe` package to estimate a panel regression model where `conversion` is a binary variable. I know that ultimately logistic regression should be used, however, a professor suggested using linear regression first as an estimate of the parameters (to see if they make intuitive sense) and then if they make sense use logistic regression, which takes much more time on a large dataset. I am running into the following problem, which results in a few of the parameters to be `NA`. Do you know what could be done to fix this?

```
Call:
   felm(formula = conversion ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 + x5 * x6 * x7 * x8 | 
        as.factor(week) + as.factor(tenure) + as.factor(gender) + 
        as.factor(age) + as.factor(education) | 0 | user_id, data 
        = data) 

Warning message:
In chol.default(mat, pivot = TRUE, tol = tol) :
Call: matrix is either rank-deficient or indefinite
```

Comment: You should talk to a statistician about the goals of your investigation. The problem will not be solved by using logistic regression since it is the "x" variables (and perhaps the small size of your data object) that are the problem.

Comment: @42- Actually the data is large (between 200k-400k depending on sample). What do you mean by "The problem will not be solved by using logistic regression since it is the "x" variables"?

Comment: The "size" that is important are the number of unique items in the rows. If those 5, x6,x7,x8 are discrete (factors) the effective size of that formula explodes. The second part of the RHS likewise creates the potential for singularity.  The RHS side of a formula rather than the link function determines whether the model matrix is invertible. I say again, ... You need to talk to a statistician.

Comment: @42- Thanks for a more detailed explanation. I should have been more precise, x5-x8 variables are binary factors. After removing one of the four, there seems to be no problem anymore.

Comment: I agree that this is not a perfect solution and deeper understanding of the problem is necessary. If you have any good resources describing what you mean I would be grateful for sharing those.

Comment: I've given a constructive response to you follow-on question. I continue to think you need further statistical education.

Comment: I thoiught there were issues that needed further study for the questioner to get to a point of understanding the substantive issues that might or might not be involved. Remember that only a model specification was offered and no data or presentation of the underlying problem were presented.  I don't think reducing the number of factors necessarily "solves the problem". And I don't think asking for references to theoretic background material is on-topic for SO.